# General Error Handler for Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

So far I have around 4 calls to my API using Restangular and in each one of them I have been checking for them on the second argument of the then as shown below:

```
Restangular.all("accounts").getList().then(function() {
   console.log("All ok");
}, function(response) {
   console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
});
```

As you can see this is not a maintainable approach since this creates a lot of duplicate error handling code across the application.

I understand that the [errorInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor) exists however I cannot imagine a use for it to create a general error handler.

I hope that maybe some new ideas can help me on this issue.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of to check do we have a specific error handler in the promise chain or not, I added my general error handler to be cancellable in later of the promise chain:

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(
      function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
            var generalHandlerTimer = $timeout(function(){
              generalErrorHanding(response);
            },1);
            response.cancelGeneralHandler = function(){
              $timeout.cancel(generalHandlerTimer);
            };
            return true; // continue the promise chain
      }
);
```

and a call where error can happen:

```
restangularizedUser.patch({
          user: {
            email:newValue
          }
        }).then(function(res) {
                //Success
           }, function(response) {
                //Error
                //Cancel the general error handler due to I want to handle it on my way
              response.cancelGeneralHandler();
              $log.debug('Handle the ERROR on my specific way');
        });
```

Disadvantage:

- If you need to use a specific error handler, then you need to call the `response.cancelGeneralHandler();`

Advantage:

- No hack is required :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Problem with errorInterceptor is that it is called before any callbacks so we have an option to do something always not only when we need it. I solved this problem in hacky way so it's up to you whether you'll use it in your code or not. Works fine on:

```
"angular": "1.3.0",
"restangular": "1.4.0",
```

First I do use errorInterceptor:

```
RestangularConfigurer.setErrorInterceptor(function (response, deferred, responseHandler) {
    var hasSomeErrback = deferred.promise.$$state.pending.map(function (thenAttachment) {
        if (thenAttachment[2]) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }).reduce(function (accumulator, value) {
        return accumulator || value
    }, false)

    if (!hasSomeErrback) {
        myErrorService.globalError()
    }
})
```

But instead of calling global error handler (myErrorService.globalError()) every time I do it only when there are not error callbacks registered. This is quite hacky, as it uses interal data of promise object but seems to work, see tests:

```
describe('when server responded with error', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(myErrorService, 'globalError')
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/evil').respond(500, 'pure evil')
    })

    it('should call global error handler if error callback was NOT attached', function () {
        myApiClient.all('evil').getList().then(function () {

        })

        $httpBackend.flush()

        expect(myErrorService.globalError).toHaveBeenCalled()

    })

    it('shouldnt call global error handler if error callback was attached', function () {
        myApiClient.all('evil').getList().then(function () {

        }, function () {
            console.log('Inside local catch')
        })

        $httpBackend.flush()

        expect(myErrorService.globalError).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    })

    it('shouldnt call global error handler if error callback was attached using catch', function () {
        myApiClient.all('evil').getList().catch(function () {

        })

        $httpBackend.flush()

        expect(myErrorService.globalError).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

Comment: Copied from http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUuADiQ_a5vEqxqlK7FY/general-error-handler-for-restangular.html